# Slider Working in Firefox But Funky in Chrome/Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Any ideas how I can get this slider working right? I'm using a slider I found here:
http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

It's a custom WordPress theme that I'm nearing the end of developing. When I load the internal pages, that use this slider, on Firefox they seem to work right. But when I load them up on Chrome/Safari they sit loading a semi-transparent slide, then sorta shift around, then start to run ok afterwards. But the loading of the slider is quite funky. You can see what I'm talking about on the dev site here for example.

http://supreme.asenka.com/brands/garden-fresh/

Not really sure what the problem could be. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like it comes down to the images being loaded. If you reload the page after the first time you load it, it works fine. You would need to wait for the images to be loaded in the dom, until the slider starts.

Comment: Try the following: In your code, where you call the slick plugin, wrap the call with this function: $(window).load(function() {
    $('yourdiv').slick();
});

Comment: Instead of window you can also use the container containing your images. You should add an id to the container(large-5 if i see it right). Then you can replace 'window' with the id

Comment: Thanks, Mr. Wittle! I had it wrapped in regular document/ready tags, but for some reason window/load seems to work better. I'm no wiz at jQuery/JS so I'm not exactly sure why, document/ready seems like it should work too (if not better), but who am I to argue. It doesn't load the first time 100% smoothly still, but I think it will suffice. Thanks!!! :)

Comment: Wrote you an answer, I hope this helps. If you want, I can look into your edited page also.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the following function around your `$('.yourdiv').slick();`:

```
$('#div-containing-your-images').load(function(){
    $('.yourdiv').slick();
}
```

The difference between document.ready and document.load is the following:

document.ready will fire, once all html elements are rendered. Once the  tag for example is rendered, it will fire. It doesn't matter, if the image itself is already loaded.

document.load will fire, once all objects, iframes, images are loaded into your page. For example, if you have an `<img src="yoursource.jpg"/>` it will fire, when the image itself is loaded.